# Django ManyToMany field is not saved

Tags: django

I need to update ManyToMany field on object save.

I've tried to override save method, but it doesn't update m2m.

There is my authors field

authors = models.ManyToManyField(
to='author.Author', blank=True
)

And save method is

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Album, self).save(*args,  **kwargs)

    sounds = self.sounds.all()
    authors = [author for sound in sounds for author in sound.authors.all()]
    self.authors.set(authors)
        
    print(self.authors.all())
```

In output `<QuerySet [<Author: Slick Killa>, <Author: 6feetdeep>]>`, but database have not changed

I will be glad of any help :)

Changed 1

Album model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, default='Not titled album'
    )
    cover = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/covers/albums'
    )
    sounds = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='Sound'
    )
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='author.Author', blank=True
    )
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Album, self).save(*args,  **kwargs)
        
        sounds = self.sounds.all()
        authors = [author for sound in sounds for author in sound.authors.all()]

        self.authors.clear()
        for author in authors:
            self.authors.add(author)

        print(self.authors.all())
```

Author model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, default='Not titled author'
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, default=None, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

Sound model

```
class Sound(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, default='Not titled sound'
    )
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        'author.Author'
    )
    sound = models.FileField(
        upload_to='files/sounds'
    )
    cover = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/covers/sounds', null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title}, {self.authors.all()[0].title}'
```

Note! Author model locate in other app, called author

Comment: Could you please share all of the relevant pieces of code ? especially the models

Comment: @Alombaros I've write models to question

Comment: add the line self.authors.save() to save the m2m field .